# Compare Multiple Sheets to output commonalities

Tags: excel-2010

I am looking for some direction/advice/suggestions/examples from the experts out there on comparing multiple sheets. What I have is approx. 250 jobs that run through machines which first require parts to be setup. The parts that need to be setup come from an inventory of approx. 3000 parts.

Many of the jobs use "common" parts between them.  I have gone the long way first by having a master sheet with all of my 3000 "Parts" and approx 200 sheets of "JOB Part Lists", then I am using "Index/Match" to find how many jobs utilize each part to obtain a list of the "Highest Used" parts.

The last part gets much more complicated. I am trying to determine the BEST method for setting up as many jobs at one time as possible to reduce the setup time for these parts. The limitation I have is that I can only setup a maximum of 264 parts for any combination of jobs. So my end result will be, in what order should the jobs run to utilize the most parts that are setup.

Example:  Based on common parts found and space available, the first setup list might be:

```
JOB-1, 
JOB-6, 
JOB-9, 
JOB-14, 
JOB-19
```

which show the MOST common between all jobs.

Second round:

```
JOB-2, 
JOB-3,  
JOB-28, 
JOB-30, 
JOB-37.
```

Based on space limitations, 47 parts might be left on from the first round to the second and so on.  Excel might not even be the tool for such comparison, so I am just asking for advice.

@SteveLovell  - this was my other question for you.

Comment: It sounds like a database would be a smarter solution.

Comment: @Strawberry that was my fear as I know very little about databases. I have searched google for days trying to find something close to what I need but with no luck.

Comment: So, a job can't 'run' unless all its parts are set up?

Comment: Actually, this sounds like an np-complete problem - not the kind of thing that conventional databases are best able to solve, but they can solve them using a rather blunt approach.

Comment: Each job can run individually, but typically 5-6 jobs can run each day. Its a matter of finding common for several jobs

Comment: `Find the most common(ality) between all jobs` - I still don't really understand what this means.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following assemblies:

```
smooth red box
smooth yellow box
perforated red cylinder
smooth shiny yellow pyramids
```

These assemblies require the following tools/equipment

```
sander
red paint
box former
yellow paint
perforater
cylinder former
polisher
pyramid former
```

But what's the 'most common' in this example, and how does that answer change if we can only use a limited number of tools at once?

Comment: sander and polisher would most likely be common and used on all assemblies. so with the space we have, we might be able to build all except the red cylinder. so it will have to wait until the next round.

Comment: I will put into terms most related to what I can see physically on my end.

Comment: Well sander is common to 3 things. Box former, yellow paint, and red paint are all variously related to two things. But I'm still not sure how that helps us get to an answer

Comment: I have a machine that holds parts, the same kind used in your cell phone. I have mechanical boxes that hold 33 part types. The machine holds 8 boxes. Cell phones for example: I build 200 cell phone models using approx 2000 different parts. How many cell phone models can I build and reduce my setup time of parts?  So "Part-A", "Part-B", "Part-C" are common to ALL models so I need to be sure those are setup at all times. Now I need to determine the method to find as many common parts as possible to tell me which models I can build, but that won't exceed the max number of spots available.

Comment: On average each model uses 80-100 parts but with many common parts to other models. *** I should clarify, many models might only take 10 part types, so they would easily fill in.

Comment: Yes, for clarity, I was trying to simplify the problem